# How to convert my online pine scripts to indicators for the charting library?

Tags: javascript, html, pine-script, tradingview-api

I've been through hundreds of sites, articles, repositories and chat rooms to try and find out how I could convert my scripts from the TV website into custom studies for the charting library. Most of the sites or guides say `"send us your scripts and we'll convert them for you"` ?!?! (is that a joke?)

I'm aware of the [documentation](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki) site but there's no info about the `metainfo: {}` options or the constructor.

Any direction to guides or documentation on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Basic implementation: https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Creating-Custom-Studies Then for examples, you have to dig through the issues tab on github (search "pine") for answers like this: https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Creating-Custom-Studies in short, you can either call a custom symbol and get data from your server, or perform all of the calculations in the constructor function using the `PineJS.Std` wrapper and using the examples found in the issues tab.

Comment: the issue board for this library is terribly inconsistent, but you've pointed me to exactly what i need (or can get for now!). would be nice to do a video series on this. maybe i'll think about it :P .. cheers!

Comment: any update on this question ?

Comment: @chiragsorathiya they've been completely unhelpful with this request. last I remember, they deprecated this feature or told me they have no plans for future support. hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks 4Umninja yes I found plans for future support thanks for the answer.